# SAS : ERROR Attempt to change the value of a string in PRXCHANGE

Tags: sas

I have this code :

```
%global nb_usag;
%global usager_entr;

%let nb_usag=0;
%syslput nb_usag=&nb_usag;

%let usager_entr=u;

PROC SQL noprint ;
    select count(distinct no_usager_entr) into :nb_usag  from &lib..INSCRITS_USA_1
    ;
quit;

data _null_;
    if &nb_usag > 0 then do;
        call execute
            ("PROC SQL noprint ;
            select distinct no_usager_entr INTO :usager_entr separated by ','

            from &lib..INSCRITS_USA_1;")
        ;
        if &usager_entr ne "u" then do;
            call prxchange('s/,/\",\"',-1,&usager_entr);
        end;
    end;
run;

%let usager_entr="&usager_entr";
%syslput usager_entr=&usager_entr;
%put &nb_usag;
%put &usager_entr;
```

But the code generate this error for the function prxchange:

```
ERROR 135-185: Attempt to change the value of the constant 's/,/\",\"' in the PRXCHANGE subroutine call.
```

What I am doing wrong?

I want to modify every , in the variable usager_entr with ",".

For example, if `usager_entr = 12121212,34343434,56565656` it will become `12121212","34343434","56565656`.

In my case the table &lib..INSCRITS_USA_1 is empty, then nb_usag=0.

Thanks!

Comment: Call EXECUTE runs at the end of the data step. So your macro variable &usager _entr is not available for usage when you try and use it. Not sure what you're expecting from the PRXCHANGE either.

Comment: @Reeza. Thank you for your answer. What I want to do : the variable usager_entr is filled with values from  &lib..INSCRITS_USA_1, separated by a ,. I want to modify every comma with "," = double quotes comma double quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too much fooling around!  Instead, create the double quoted list of values directly from `Proc SQL`

Presuming the list will be used in a later clause with the construct `IN (&myList)`.

```
%let usager_entr_dq_csv_list = "redundant safety value that will never match anything";

PROC SQL noprint ;
    select distinct quote(trim(no_usager_entr))
    INTO :usager_entr_dq_csv_list separated by ','
    from &lib..INSCRITS_USA_1;
```

The redundant value is needed because if it were empty you would later generate `IN ()` and have a syntax error.

If the list is being used in pass-through SQL you will want to use the additional arguments of `QUOTE` function to bound the values with a single quote.

Answer (score 2):

For modify your macro variable from usager_entr = 12121212,34343434,56565656 to  "12121212","34343434","56565656", you could use prxchange:

```
%let usager_entr =12121212,34343434,56565656;
%put &usager_entr;
%let New_usager_entr=%sysfunc(prxchange(s/([1-9]+)/"$1"/, -1,%quote(&usager_entr)));
%put &New_usager_entr;
```